# How to format time in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am new to SSRS reports

I have time intervals as (`1230, 1300, 1330,1400,1430,1500,1530`)
I wanted to display them as (`12:30pm, 1:00pm, 1:30pm, 2:00pm, 2:30pm, 3:00pm, 3:30pm`) respectively.

How to achieve this in SSRS??

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following.

```
Format(CDate(Fields!YourTimeString.Value),"hh:mm tt")
```

Where `YourTimeString` is the time string. `tt` will give you the `am\pm`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click on the textbox with your data and go to 'Textbox Properties...', and under the 'Number' tab, you can choose the format you would like the data to be shown in.